# Swift color change shows different color

Tags: swift, uiimage, tint

I am trying to do a scale animation on an image view. Upon completion I am changing the image to a red colored version of it. But in between **it shows a weird blue color** which I dont want to show. This is the code I am using for the animation. Thanks

```
 self.likeAnimateView.image = self.likeAnimateView.image!.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.182,
                        animations: {
                           self.likeAnimateView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

                        },
                        completion: { _ in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.182) {
                                self.likeAnimateView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

                                  self.likeAnimateView.image = UIImage(named: "heartsel") // Red image
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: Can you show the heartsel image and what you saw on the screen (the blue one)? Also, what was in the image view before the animation?

Comment: The Blue is default for rendering mode. Change the color what you want before animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion of @Karthikeyan Bose. I added this line of code before the animation.

```
self.likeAnimateView.image = UIImage(named: "heart")//Deafault color before the animation to get rid of the blue color

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.182,
               animations: {
                   self.likeAnimateView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

               },
               completion: { _ in
                   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.182) {
                       self.likeAnimateView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

                       self.likeAnimateView.image = UIImage(named: "heartsel") // Red image
                   }
               })
```